# Get term_taxonomy_id from return of wp_insert_post

Tags: terms

I am trying to get the term_taxonomy_id from the returned array of wp_insert_term.
Below is my code.  The term is correctly added to the db, but it fails when i try to get the id and save it to a variable.

```
$menu_term = wp_insert_term('Main Menu','nav_menu');
$menu_tax = $menu_term['term_taxonomy_id'];
```

Comment: Do you definitely need `term_taxonomy_id`, or will `term_id` do?

Comment: I need the 'term_taxonomy_id' to so that i can use wp_set_object_terms to assign nav_menu_items to the term

Comment: I think you'll need to use [`get_term_by`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by)